# Dropzone delete uploaded images from server

Tags: c#, dropzone.js

I use dropzone.js for my image uploading to the server.
Now I want to be able to delete the just uploaded images in the dropzone.

My dropzone config:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
   paramName: "file",
   maxFilesize: 10,
   url: '/test',
   maxFiles: 3,
   accept: function (file, done) {
      console.log(file);
      if (file.type !== "image/jpeg" && file.type !== "image/png" && file.type !== "application/pdf") {
        done("Error! Files of this type are not accepted");
      }
      else { done(); }},
   addRemoveLinks: true
};
```

The `addRemoveLinks: true` enables the delete button on the thumbnails but this only removes the thumbnails in the dropzone.
The actual files are still in place on the server.

Upload code:

```
  foreach (string s in Request.Files)
  {
     _file = Request.Files[s];
     var pathToFile = Path.Combine(physicalPathToDirectory, _file.FileName);

     _file.SaveAs(pathToFile);

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an init function to your dropzone options object, and listen for the removedfile event.

```
init: function() {
    this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
        //add in your code to delete the file from the database here 
    });
}
```

It's all there in the docs.  Find the "listen to events" section for more information.  http://www.dropzonejs.com/